# On laptop, left speaker gets very quiet at random

Tags: sound, laptop, hp

On a relatively fresh Ubuntu install, and having an issue where my left speaker will suddenly get very quiet then go back to normal, sometimes multiple times in a minute.

I'm using a HP Spectre x360 14.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.